# How to make comments for custom post type best way

Tags: custom-post-types

I made a company catalog using custom posts. So right now I can write comments to any company using default comment system but got 2 problems:

1. comments from companies shown at frontend with comments from other posts
2. comments from companies shown at backend comments list

I think about filter by post_type in [post_fields:protected] array and about creating other custom post type for company comments.

Which way is possible and better for future develompent?

Comment: Maybe use [add_comment_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_comment_meta/) to help distinguish between comments on the different post-types. And modify the add-comment form and comments-list template to use the comment_meta differently depending on if the comment is being made on a post-type.

Comment: Is it possible to hide custom post comments in any theme? Can comments-list template add only filter to theme template?

Comment: How to post meta value from comment_form? I use add_comment_meta but can't get value from form.